# Can someone elaborate on the necessary proxy settings in the install-config.yaml file for an OKD installation in an air-gapped environment?

Tags: proxy, openshift, okd

I am attempting an installation of OKD 4.5 in a restricted (i.e. air-gapped) environment. I am running into an issue during the installation process where-in, as far as I can tell, the bootstrap machine is attempting and failing to access the mirrored registry I have running.

Based on my research, I believe this issue is stemming from a lack of proxy settings within the `install-config.yaml` file as described [in the documentation here](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-restricted-networks-bare-metal.html#installation-configure-proxy_installing-restricted-networks-bare-metal), however I am having trouble wrapping my brain around what functions I'm attempting to accommodate by adding this proxy information into the configuration and exactly what information I should be adding. I haven't been able to find any other segments of the documentation that go into details about this either (however if someone can simply point me in the direction of such documentation, that would be extremely helpful).

Would anyone be willing to explain to me what values should be going into the proxy lines in this file and why? Does this information replace, compliment, or require changes in any way to the `networking` segment of the configuration?

As a related question, do I need to change any of the networking subnet values to reflect my local network? In all examples I've seen the `clusterNetwork.cidr` and `serviceNetwork` subnets are the same as the documentation (`cidr: 10.128.0.0/14`, `serviceNetwork: - 172.30.0.0/16`), and some include an additional `machineNetwork` field. Is this field something I should be adding and if so, should I just be including my subnet for this field?

As context for my specific scenario, here are my environment specifications as well as the specific errors I am getting:

```
 OKD Release: `4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428`
 Environment: Virtualized Bootstrap, Master and Worker nodes, in virt-manager, running on Centos 7 in 
 air-gapped environment. This host machine contains the install directory and also provides DNS, 
 Apache Server, HAProxy for load balancing and the mirrored registry.
```

Errors:

```
 From <log-bundle>/bootstrap/journals/release-image.log: 
 localhost.localdomain release-image-download.sh[114151]: Error: Error initializing source docker://okd-services.okd.local:5000/okd@sha256<.....>: 
 error pinging docker registry okd-services.okd.local:5000: Get "https://okd-services.okd.local:5000/v2/": 
 dial tcp <okd-services.okd.local ip>:5000: connect: connection refused

 From systemctl status named (several requests to IPs I don't recognize which seem to be NTP requests):
 network unreachable resolving '2.fedora.pool.ntp.org.okd/AAAA..
 network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 199.7.91.13#53
 etc
```

I have ensured that host-node and node-node communication is present, and that the registry is accessible from the nodes ( to test, I netcat the certificate pem into a node and update its trusts, then `curl -u` the registry using `https://fqdn:5000/v2/_catalog`), so I am fairly certain all the connections are established properly.

To conclude, since I'm fairly sure that the proxy/network settings in the `install-config.yaml` file are to blame, and since I am unable to find more elaboration on these configurations in the official docs or elsewhere, I would very much appreciate any in-depth explanation of how I should be configuring this for an air-gapped environment. Additionally, if anyone believes that another issue is the cause, any input regarding that would be great.